# Filter that shows only the questions I haven't read

Tags: feature-request

I am a big fun of *Mathematica*.SE, and I've already learned a lot more just scanning through questions. This is an awesome community and the moderators and highly rated members are doing excellent work.

I like a lot the * mark where I mark a question as favorite and read it again in the future.

I am wondering if there is an option to filter all questions of the forum I haven't read (as logged in).

So there is the: All Questions bar, *newest, featured, frequent, votes, active, unanswered*. Could it be possible to have also an additional option: *unread*?

Comment: This would almost certainly be a network-wide change, so you I think would do better to ask for features like this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.  However, I believe this has been asked before and rejected.  Let me look... OK, here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100626/hide-viewed-questions

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard , maybe we will see it globally in a future SE update.

Comment: Duplicate: [Can we set up bookmarks in SE?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/370)

Comment: How would you have the site determine that you'd read a given question?